# Make a line break in a value of textarea in PHP

Tags: php, textarea, line-breaks

So here's an example of a value inside a textarea.

```
Welcome to my site

Blah blah blah?
```

And when echo the value it goes like this:

```
Welcome to my site Blah blah blah?
```

How can line break it without typing... \n or < br > using PHP

Or for a good example. Like we have here in Stack Overflow when you ask a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert linebreaks to `<br />` with [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

Comment: I have a variable $dmessage so I'll just make it as nl2br($dmessage)? Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`nl2br()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) while posting the value. Enter values in textarea for new line you can use enter key see the example.

```
<textarea name="description" rows="5" class="input"></textarea>
   echo  nl2br($_POST['description']);
```

Answer (score -2):

[`nl2br`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

> Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string